# Can we add the Shipping and Billing addresses form in the cart.liquid file?

Tags: javascript, shopify, cart, liquid

I want to add the Shipping and Billing addresses form in the cart.liquid file so it is possible to add these two addresses form in cart page if anybody known then give solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Shipping and Billing address are collected in Checkout step, not the cart step.

Comment: You cannot mix up the cart with checkout. They are two separate and distinct things. If you work with Shopify Plus, you will see that checkout options directly affect the cart, but you won't see that on a regular shop.

Comment: Just want to add a thought - one thing you can do -- technically -- is allow anyone who is logged in as a customer to change/edit/add their address from the checkout page. 

It'd take some elbow grease, but theoretically it is possible. 

And if you want to be a pain in the butt to customers, you can force them to have to be a customer with an account first before they checkout. I personally don't suggest that, but I think it's a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as of now. Soon after user clicks on checkout button, they are redirected to shopify's checkout system. that is https://checkout.shopify.com.
You would not have any option to send your address data from cart page to checkout page.